# Detect whether device can receive sms

Tags: ios

I want to detect if iOS device can receive sms. From first look, I can use the code below:

```
+(bool)canDeviceSendSms {
// Check if the device can send sms
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://"]]) {
    // Device supports sms, lets confirm it can place one right now
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
    NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
    if (([mnc length] == 0) || ([mnc isEqualToString:@"65535"])) {
        // Device cannot send sms at this time.  SIM might be removed.
        return NO;
    } else {
        // Device can send sms
        return YES;
    }
} else {
    // Device does not support sms sending
    return  NO;
}
```

}

However, my iPad 4 with sim card returns me YES, when by itself it is not able to receive sms. It has iMessage, but for instance I haven't authorized any account in iMessage, so probably I won't receive any sms. How can I detect sms receiving capability and exclude iMessage.

Comment: when returning YES there u can check where its iPhone or iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to detect if iPad can send sms as well, so it should return **NO** if iMessage not configured. use method **canSendText** from  **MFMessageComposeViewController**.

check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText

> Before presenting a message composition view, call the canSendText
>   class method to ensure that the user’s device is appropriately
>   configured. Do not attempt to present a message composition view if
>   the canSendText method returns NO. If neither iMessage nor SMS/MMS
>   (Short Message Service/Multimedia Messaging Service) delivery is
>   available, you can notify the user or simply disable the messaging
>   features in your app.