# Get state of settings in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, imessage

Could somebody tell me, how can I find out programatically the state of settings, for example if "Send as SMS" is enabled in Messages application? I know how to programatically open this part of settings but I just want actual value.(I want to find out, if user can send sms or just iMessage to iPhone users)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect whether device can receive sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107143/detect-whether-device-can-receive-sms)

Comment: @Cristik thanks but that doesnt solve my problem. I actually want to know, if user can send also sms messages to another iPhone users or just iMessages